# Get current route without parameters

Tags: angular, url, angular2-routing, angular2-router

I need to get my current route without params in Angular 2, I found a way to get the current route with params as follows:

```
 this.router.url
```

and then split it:

```
 this.router.url.split(';')[0]
```

But this looks as workaround, I think there should be better way?

Comment: `this.dom.URL.split('?')[0]` ->  where dom is instance of `DOCUMENT`

Comment: The "angular" way would be to import Router from `@angular/router` and then *"simply"* use `this.router.parseUrl(this.router.url).root.children.primary.segments`. If the goal was to make as many developers as possible prefer Vue or React over Angular, it's a job very well done. Hat off, Angular architects! And no, providing subscriptions is not enough. What if I want to get the activated route params in a component created after route has changed (i.e: a modal)? You need to expose subscriptions as well as methods to get the current value. Make it easy to use for children! That's your goal!

Answer (score 54):

To get current route without query parameters, you can use below mentioned single line:

```
this.router.url.split('?')[0]
```

Comment: How your approach is different from the one OP mentioned in his question (`this.router.url.split(';')[0]`)?

Comment: shouldn't you subscribe to an observable?

Comment: this was the best solution for my use case, since it uses an Angular service, which makes it a lot easier to stub out in testing

Answer (score 44):

`parseTree` from `Router` helps fetching the segments without any knowledge about url structure.

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
...
constructor(private router: Router) {}
...
const urlTree = this.router.parseUrl(url);
const urlWithoutParams = urlTree.root.children['primary'].segments.map(it => it.path).join('/');
```

Start from here. If you have secondary outlets adjust as required.

Comment: If `url` is `/`, there are no primary children. So, `urlWithoutParam` should be `/` if `urlTree.root.children.primary` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 29):

For me, this is the cleanest solution I managed to do. I hope it helps

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    
constructor(private router: Router){}

getUrlWithoutParams(){
   let urlTree = this.router.parseUrl(this.router.url);
   urlTree.queryParams = {}; 
   urlTree.fragment = null; // optional
   return urlTree.toString();
}
```

Comment: no need to use `let` here, it's ok to use `const`

Comment: nice strategy, I tried some variation with urlTree... the only thing is that I think it makes testing harder?

Comment: @ahong i guess it might be harder, but i think the "split" methods mentioned in other answers are the hardest when it comes to testing

Comment: we are using a mock router for our tests so the `parseUrl` method is not available. Seems like someone recommended the `RouterTestingModule` https://stackoverflow.com/a/59855413/2088345. It was just a bit more set up.

Comment: awesome! just 1 more thing `urlTree.fragment = null;` in case you use that.

Comment: Thank you @Shadoweb, I will add it to the answer

Answer (score 13):

Short and simple pure js.

```
location.pathname
```

Comment: ROFL. I wonder if anyone could provide a hint of why not just use this clean and sweet solution as compared to the angular centric solutions.

Comment: @Harald If you are in a SSR environment with Angular, `window` and `location` are not available.

Comment: Exactly. SSR makes it impossible on the server-side, though for many other use-cases, `location.pathname` would be ideal.

Comment: It's not work for hash route. for example, `http://example.com/#/app?x=1`

Comment: It may be easier to migrate if using Angular API. I think.

Answer (score 5):

Native javascript will work to split the url into logical parts. Check out the "location" (or window.location) object. For example, using location at the url https://example.com/pathname1/pathname2?queryParam1=1&queryParam2=2 yields

```
location.origin === 'https://example.com/pathname1/pathname2'
location.href === 'https://example.com/pathname1/pathname2?queryParam1=1&queryParam2=2'
location.pathname === '/pathname1/pathname2'
location.search === '?queryParam1=1&queryParam2=2'
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using **webpack**, you can use the `url` **polyfill** module which comes bundled, along with the Angular `Router` module.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import * as url from 'url'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  public constructor(public readonly router: Router) {}

  public ngOnInit() {
    const urlInfo = url.parse(this.router.url)
    console.log(urlInfo.pathname)
  }
}
```

Comment: any disadvantages to using the webpack polyfill? Just a bit too coupled to webpack or is it pretty standard?

Comment: deprecated — since v11.0.0 - Use the WHATWG URL API https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_pathname

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar requirement, depending on which route I used to get the component I wanted different outcomes.

I found that `activatedRoute.routeConfig.path` was a great option and made it easy for me to see which route had been used.

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}
ngOnInit() {
  if (this.activatedRoute.routeConfig.path === 'heroes/:id')
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. `this.activatedRoute.routeConfig.path` returns a blank string.

Answer (score 2):

this could help you:

1. Import *Router*:

   ```
   import { Router } from '@angular/router';
   ```
2. Signature in the **constructor**:

   ```
   constructor(private _router: Router) {}
   ```
3. Check the **_router** events property:

   ```
   this._router.events
       .subscribe(
           (url:any) => {
               let _ruta = "";
               url.url.split("/").forEach(element => {
                   if(element!=="" && _ruta==="")
                       _ruta="/"+element;
                   });
               console.log("route: "+_ruta); //<<<---- Root path
               console.log("to URL:"+url.url); //<<<---- Destination URL 
               console.log("from URL:"+this._router.url);//<<<---- Current URL
           });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

To get current route without query parameters, you can use below mentioned single line:

```
this.url = this.url.substr(0, this.url.lastIndexOf("?"));
```

Answer (score 1):

this worked like a charm for me:

```
  currentUrl: string;

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const urlTree: UrlTree = this.router.parseUrl(this.router.url);
    const urlSegmentGroup: UrlSegmentGroup = urlTree.root.children['primary'];
    this.currentUrl = urlSegmentGroup ? urlSegmentGroup.segments.map((it) => it.path).join('/') : '';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to compare the previous route and the new route, when changing only the **:id** on the url via **router.navigate**. Since I wanted the path without the different ids, I got the original path of the route:

```
/* 
    Routes = [
        { path: 'main/details/:id', component: DetailComponent }
    ]

    previousRoute = '/main/details/1'
    newRoute      = '/main/details/2'
*/

this.routeSubscription = this.router.events.filter((event) => event instanceof ResolveStart)
                                           .pairwise() // returns previous and current events
                                           .subscribe((ev: [ResolveStart, ResolveStart]) => {

    let sameRoute = ev[0].state.root.firstChild.routeConfig.path == ev[1].state.root.firstChild.routeConfig.path ?
                       ev[0].state.root.firstChild.routeConfig.path : undefiend;
    if (sameRoute) {
        // Same routes, probably different ids 
        console.log(sameRoute) // gives 'main/details/:id'
    } else {
        // Different routes
    }
});
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, the event had no state property

Answer (score 0):

I use locationStrategy like in accept answer but with `.split()` method. LocationStrategy work perfect in Angular 4 & Angular 5;

```
import {LocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';

export class MyService {
    constructor(private locationStrategy: LocationStrategy) {
    }

    public getUrl(filters: FilterConfig[]): void {
        const url = this.locationStrategy.path();
        const urlArray = url.split('?');

        return urlArray[0];
    }
}
```

One more things you should carry about is to be sure that your `<router-outlet>` is properly initialize before you try to get `locationStrategy.path()`. If `<router-outlet>` isn't initialize any Angular services can't return URL and query params properly.

To be sure that you location strategy is initialize you can use subscribe method like:

```
this.router.events.subscribe((evt) => {
...
}
```

But in this case you trigger your function on each router change so you need to protect this case if it's unwanted.

Answer (score 0):

None of these worked for me.

There are many approaches to this, but in this case a guard was in place to stop users going to specific URL's. This worked fine except when URL's had parameters as the passed URL always contained all the parameters.

E.G: `myPage/param1/param2`

Or:  `myPage?param1=1&param2=2`

In this case I'd want just *`myPage`*.

I coded the below, I don't like it, I'm sure it can be improved but haven't found anything else that works so far:

```
    let url: string = state.url;
    let urlParams: string[];

    if (url.includes("?")) {
        url = url.substr(0, url.indexOf('?'));
    } else {
        urlParams = route.url.toString().split(';')[0].split(',');

        if (urlParams.length > 1) {
            urlParams.shift(); // Remove first element which is page name

            // Get entire splitting on each param
            let fullUrlSegments: string[] = state.url.split('/');
            // Remove number of params from full URL
            fullUrlSegments = fullUrlSegments.slice(0, fullUrlSegments.length - urlParams.length);

            url = fullUrlSegments.join('/');
        }
    }

    alert(url);
```

`state.url` comes from the implementation for `CanActivate` (or inject `Router`).

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) Observable<boolean> { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use URL https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL

```js
const url = new URL("https://example.org/route/test?test")
const path = url.origin + url.pathname
```

But does not work in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Using Angular `PlatformLocation`:

```js
@Component{...}
// or
@Service{...}
export class Some {
constructor(private platformLocation: PlatformLocation) {
  console.log(this.platformLocation.pathname);
}
```