# angular: how to get parameters from url

Tags: angular

i'm using **angular**
i have this router

```
{ path: 'inbox/:email',        component: InboxMessagesComponent  },
```

and i'm trying to get the **email** parameter using this code

```
this.email = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('email') ;
```

the url i have :
**http://localhost:4200/inbox/test@email.com?folder=INBOX** 
and the result  i get is like that:

```
email: "test@email.com?folder=INBOX"
```

but i'm expecting that **email** should equal only **test@email.com**
where do i have the problem and how can i fix that please ?!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get current route without parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42504809/get-current-route-without-parameters)

Comment: try this.route.paramMap.get('email)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
this.email = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('email').split("?")[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should consider always using the Observable `BehaviourSubject` which is the best approach

```
 this.route.params.subscribe((p) => {
    const email = p['email']||'';
})
```

This will work each time the params change then email will be refreshed with the actual value.