# how to extend functionality from BrowserPlatformLocation

Tags: angular, typescript

I was looking for a way to get the current route without parameters.

I found this answer for example:
[Get current route without parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42504809/get-current-route-without-parameters)

Like you can see there are many workarounds but no one of them is simple and clear.

When I was using "`location.path()`" I noticed thet it uses "`BrowserPlatformLocation.pathname()`" that contains the "current route without parameters".

So the question is:

How can I extend functionality from "`BrowserPlatformLocation`".